# Creating Connection for RedshiftDataOperator

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-redshift, aws-api-gateway

So i when to the airflow documentation for aws redshift there is 2 operator that can execute the sql query they are RedshiftSQLOperator and RedshiftDataOperator. I already implemented my job using RedshiftSQLOperator but i want to do it using RedshiftDataOperator instead, because i dont want to using postgres connection in RedshiftSQLOperator but AWS API.

[RedshiftDataOperator Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/redshift_data/index.html)

I had read this documentation there is aws_conn_id in the parameter. But when im trying to use the same connection id there is error.

```
[2023-01-11, 04:55:56 UTC] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID 'redshift_default' for task execution.
[2023-01-11, 04:55:56 UTC] {base_aws.py:206} INFO - Credentials retrieved from login
[2023-01-11, 04:55:56 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1889} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/redshift_data.py", line 146, in execute
    self.statement_id = self.execute_query()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/redshift_data.py", line 124, in execute_query
    resp = self.hook.conn.execute_statement(**filter_values)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 415, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 745, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

From task id

```
redshift_data_task = RedshiftDataOperator(
        task_id='redshift_data_task',
        database='rds',
        region='ap-southeast-1',
    aws_conn_id='redshift_default',
        sql="""
        call some_procedure();
        """
        )
```

What should i fill in the airflow connection ? Because in the documentation there is no example of value that i should fill to airflow. Thanks

Airflow RedshiftDataOperator Connection Required Value

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Amazon Redshift connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/redshift.html)? There is both an option for authenticating using your Redshift credentials:

```
Connection ID: redshift_default
Connection Type: Amazon Redshift
Host: <your-redshift-endpoint> (for example, redshift-cluster-1.123456789.us-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com)
Schema: <your-redshift-database> (for example, dev, test, prod, etc.)
Login: <your-redshift-username> (for example, awsuser)
Password: <your-redshift-password>
Port: <your-redshift-port> (for example, 5439)
```

([source](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-redshift#setup))

and an option for using an IAM role (there is an example in the first link).

Disclaimer: I work at Astronomer :)

EDIT: Tested the following with Airflow 2.5.0 and Amazon provider 6.2.0:

- Added the IP of my Airflow instance to the VPC security group with "All traffic" access.
- Airflow Connection with the connection id `aws_default`, Connection type "Amazon Web Services", extra: `{ "aws_access_key_id": "<your-access-key-id>",  "aws_secret_access_key": "<your-secret-access-key>",  "region_name": "<your-region-name>" }`. All other fields blank. I used a root key for my toy-aws. If you use other credentials you need to make sure that IAM role has access and the right permissions to the Redshift cluster (there is a list in the link above).
- Operator code:

```py
    red = RedshiftDataOperator(
        task_id="red", 
        database="dev",
        sql="SELECT * FROM dev.public.users LIMIT 5;",
        cluster_identifier="redshift-cluster-1",
        db_user="awsuser",
        aws_conn_id="aws_default"
    )
```

Comment: Hi i had following your source information but get error this `[2023-01-12] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID 'aws_default' for task execution.
[2023-01-12] {base_aws.py:210} INFO - Credentials retrieved from extra_config
[2023-01-12] {base_aws.py:100} INFO - Retrieving region_name from Connection.extra_config['region_name']
[2023-01-12, 08:08:21 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1889} ERROR - Task failed with exception
 An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Either ClusterIdentifier or WorkgroupName needs to be specified.`

Comment: and i have already add extra config in aws_default with "cluster_identifier": "clustername", either "ClusterIdentifier": "clustername". Is there my extra config name is wrong ?

Comment: The [RedshiftDataOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/amazon/modules/redshiftdataoperator) should have a parameter called `cluster_identifier`, have you tried specifying your cluster name there?

Comment: I added the config that works on my end in my answer. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks its worked so the cluster_identifier is not on extra config connection but in the task. Thanks a lot